# Reporting device-width for web view smaller than screen

Tags: objective-c

i have a web view embedded in one of my view controllers.  It has a rect of 600x800.  It seems like when i make a url request, its telling the web server it is 768px wide which is the width of the entire ipad in portrait.

We have the width=device-width set in the HTML header and so its giving me back a 768x#### page and causing the web view to scroll horizontally since the rect for my webview is < 768.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

How do i setup this webview so it reports the correct (smaller) width to the web server?

## Update

I did find some code set set the width in the HTML inside webViewDidFinishLoad and it does work, but is there a better way of doing this?  Seems like a hack.

```
NSString *jsCmd = @"var viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');";
jsCmd = [jsCmd stringByAppendingFormat:@"viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=%i, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1');", (NSUInteger)_webView.frame.size.width];
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCmd];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skip giving a value for width in the meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The meta tags are sent by the server and interpreted by the browser.  It is your browser (safari) who uses 768 as the size of the device-with (which is correct).

The solution is, on the server side to detect the iframe call and to send something like:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=600; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>`

In order to detect the iframe call on the server side the simplest thing is to add a URL parameter.

Comment: Thank adrian, but this wont work for iphones and ipads in landscape.  I think it makes sense to keep width=device-width on the server.  I did find a way to do it by hacking the HTTP response, but im hoping there is some cleaner way to do it.